# Adding a function to typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add a formatting function to my angular model

```
export class Site {
    Id: number;
    EstablishedDate: Date;
    CreatedDate: Date;
    ModifiedDate: Date;
    Name: string;
    URL: string;


    public Format() {
        console.log("formatting");

        return (this);
    }
}
```

to be then used like so

```
this.API.Get(params['id']).subscribe(
                res => {                       
                    this.self = res.Format();                                              
                }
            );
```

Here is the service that binds this together

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Site } from '../../models/site.model';
import { UtilitiesService } from "../utilities/utilities.service";


@Injectable()
export class SitesService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private Utils: UtilitiesService) { }

    GetAll() {
        return this.http.get<Site[]>("/sites/getall");
    }

    Get(id: string) {
        return this.http.get<Site>("/sites/get?id=" + id);
    }
}
```

This compiles fine but I get `TypeError: res.Format is not a function` on execution.

Secondary question - is there a way to trigger that function automatically as object gets populated (akin to c# constructor)?

Comment: please elaborate you service part

Comment: @AnkitKapoor done

Comment: If you debug then what are you getting in your res object ?

Comment: Appropriate data. See the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `res` is not actually of type `Site`. It will be a `JSON` object that has the data fields of the site class. You can convert the class to an interface that only has the fields, and make the method a function that takes a type of the interface, or you could add a constructor to your class and create a new object from `res`

The second option would look something like this:

```
    export class Site {
        Id: number;
        EstablishedDate: Date;
        CreatedDate: Date;
        ModifiedDate: Date;
        Name: string;
        URL: string;
        public constructor(cfg: Partial<Site>) {
            Object.assign(this, cfg);
        }
        public Format() {
            console.log("formatting");

            return (this);
        }
    }

    this.API.Get(params['id']).subscribe(
        res => {  
            const site = new Site(res);                     
            this.self = site.Format();                                              
        }
    );
```